# Windows 10 reinstall now get blue screen asking which OS to use

Tags: windows, windows-10

I've reinstalled windows 10 because I was it was playing up.  I now get a blue screen when I switch on asking to choose and operating system - Windows 10 or Windows Recovery Environment.  I chose windows 10 to be the default os but I'm just going round in circles now.  It keeps asking different things such as repair tools (which I've used) and still I get this screen when I switch on.  Can anybody help please.  Thanks.

Comment: Where did you install Windows 10 from? Did you use media creation tool?

Comment: Hi, no I reinstalled through the pc.  If I select Windows 10 on the blue screen it takes me through to Windows 10 but it's annoying that the screen appears on start up.

Answer (score 0):

Open Control Panel and then system. In system, click on advanced system settings, under startup and recovery, click settings. At the top uncheck display list of operating systems, and make sure the one you want is selected under the drop box.